# How can I split a string using a string delimeter?

Tags: c#, string, .net-4.0, split

How can I split a string using a string delimeter?

I've tried:

```
string[] htmlItems = correctHtml.Split("<tr");
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'
```

What's the recommended way to split a string on a given string parameter?

Comment: I don't see any overloads that take a string as the only parameter. Am I missing something? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Comment: @ChaosPandion: The question is how would I split a string on a given word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a version of [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) that takes a string array and an options parameter:

```
string source = "[stop]ONE[stop][stop]TWO[stop][stop][stop]THREE[stop][stop]";
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"[stop]"};
string[] result = source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

so even though you only have one separator you want to split on you still have to pass it as an array.

Taking Mike Hofer's answer as a starting point, this extension method will make it a bit simpler to use.

```
public static string[] Split(this string value, string separator)
{
    return value.Split(new string[] {separator}, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonderfully, although the code is a bit convoluted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  Regex.Split

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332139(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this the overload you are searching for?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to also use the StringSplitOptions parameter in your Split.

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension method:

```
public static string[] Split(this string value, string separator)
{
    return value.Split(separator.ToCharArray());
}
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Good idea, though this implementation will fail as the separator is longer than a single character.